# Is there any way to avoid profanity words not to be entered in list/library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise

Can we filter abusive words from entering list items?

We can override the default save function and add function to check words if present - then it can be restricted from saving, but we can't extend to all lists or new lists that will be created.

Is there any tool that helps in filtering abusive words?

It can be any platform SP-Online or SP-on prem, SP-Online is preferable.

Comment: Please specify - SharePoint Online or on-prem (which version)?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You could use the list validation to make column not contain some word.

For example, make the column not contain the word "sharepoint": `=ISERROR(FIND("sharepoint",ColumnName))`